# Datagridview populating sets of rows?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I am using mysql server in my software to connect to my database and the basic explanation is that there is a table that shows products and the number of parts they consist of. so if a product has 5 parts then I need to populate a datagridview with 5 sets of 4 rows, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

```
    public void fillTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Week", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("1", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("2", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("3", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("4", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("5", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("6", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("7", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("8", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("9", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("10", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("11", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("12", typeof(int));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "Gross Requirement";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Week"] = "On Hand";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Week"] = "Net Requirement";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Week"] = "Planned Orders";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    }
```

is it possible to make an array of datagridviews and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what your intentions are but it seems odd that you are using the same Data Row and add it many times. I think you should make a new instance of a DataRow object before adding it to the table instead of "re-initializing" the same DataRow to `dt.NewRow();` Have you tried that before? 
Can you provide an example of the structure you want to create?

```
> Product | Week | 1 | 2 | 3 ...
> ------------------------------
> Product#| text | # | # | #....
```

Also, you mention that you are using MySQL, do you have an example? Maybe a minor change to your SQL query could help.